# Is the Taylor map continuous?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, differential-equations, singularity-theory, topological-vector-spaces

(*Skip to the bolded theorem below for my question, if you'd like*)

### Some context on asymptotic expansions and the Taylor map

In the setting of irregular singularities of meromorphic connections on the punctured complex plane, not every formal solution to a differential equation $Pf = 0$ is convergent. Additionally, even if one has access to a convergent solution, it is often better (algebraically, analytically, or geometrically) to work with its asymptotic expansions -- if you remember slogging through various lectures on special functions in elementary calculus, these are the beasts to keep in mind.

Even some easy functions-- like $f(x) = \mathrm{exp}(-1/x)$, the fundamental solution to the algebraic differential equation $(x^2\frac{d}{dx}+1)f = 0$-- are asymptotic to zero as $x \to 0$ when $\mathrm{Re}(x) > 0$, but blow-up faster than any algebraic meromorphic function for $x \to 0$ when $\mathrm{Re}(x) < 0$. Consequently, the best approach when dealing with such functions is to consider their asymptotic behavior on different arc-sectors about $0$, where by an arc-sector, I mean a subset of $\mathbb{C}^*$ of the form
$$
S_r(a,b) := \{ x \in \mathbb{C} \, | \, 0 < |x|<r, a < \mathrm{arg}(x) < b\}
$$
for $r > 0$ and $a < b$ two real numbers (usually of width less than $2\pi$). An asymptotic expansion at $0$ of a function $f \in \Gamma(S_r(a,b);\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{C})$ is a formal complex power series $\hat{f} = \sum_{n \geq 0} c_n x^n \in \mathbb{C}[[x]]$ such that, for all $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and every closed subsector $W \subset S_r(a,b)$, there is a constant $C(N,W) > 0$ such that the estimate
$$
\big | f(x) - \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1}c_n x^n \big | \leq C(N,W)|x|^N
$$
holds for all $x \in W$. If such an $\hat{f}$ exists, it is unique. Let $\mathcal{A}(S_r(a,b))$ denote the subset of all such holomorphic functions with asymptotic expansions on $S_r(a,b)$, and write
\begin{align*}
J : \mathcal{A}(S_r(a,b)) &\to \mathbb{C}[[x]] \\
f &\mapsto \hat{f}
\end{align*}
for the "Taylor map" sending a function to its asymptotic expansion. To avoid dealing with issues like choosing $r>0$ small enough, we take the direct limit $\underset{r>0}{\varinjlim}\mathcal{A}(S_r(a,b)) =: \mathcal{A}(S(a,b))$ and thus obtain a sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ of differential $\mathbb{C}$-algebras on $S^1$ consisting of holomorphic functions with asymptotic expansions at $0$. A foundational result in this context is the

#### Borel-Ritt lemma:

*for any open interval $(a,b) \neq S^1$, the map $J: \mathcal{A}(S(a,b)) \to \mathbb{C}[[x]]$ is surjective.*

If we let $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ denote the constant sheaf with stalk $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$ on $S^1$, we obtain a short exact sequence of sheaves on $S^1$
$$
0 \to \mathcal{A}^0 \to \mathcal{A} \xrightarrow{J} \mathbb{C}[[x]] \to 0
$$
where $\mathcal{A}^0$ denotes the sheaf of holomorphic functions which are asymptotic to $0$ (e.g., our friend $\mathrm{exp}(-1/x)$ from earlier, on any sector contained in the right halfplane).

### My question: Is the Taylor map $J$ continuous on any proper open sector $S(a,b)$?

$\mathcal{A}(S(a,b))$ is a Fréchet space, and $\mathbb{C}[[x]]$, with its canonical $(x)$-adic topology, is a (non-archimedean) Banach space. Additionally, $\mathcal{A}^0(S(a,b))$ is a nuclear Fréchet space. To me, the criterion for $f$ to have $\hat{f}$ as its asymptotic expansion looks very much like the definition of convergence in the $(x)$-adic topology as well.

Let $S = S(a,b)$. I believe this question can be reduced to that of continuity at $0$ in $\mathcal{A}(S)$, in which case it takes the following form: let $\{f_n\}_n \subset \mathcal{A}(S)$ be a family such that $f_n \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$. Then, for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have
$$
\underset{x \to 0, x \in S}{\lim} x^{-k}f_n(x) = 0
$$
for all $0 \leq k < j$. **However, I don't know of a specific family of seminorms which generate the topology on $\mathcal{A}(S)$. Consequently, I don't know how to use the assumption that the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ converges to $0$ in $\mathcal{A}(S),$ in order to control their growth rates against the $x^{-k}$.**

Any help would be appreciated, especially if it's to tell me this claim is obviously false!